# a sequence of str_match in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

I have a string variable to parse into two parts. I figured I'd approach this using `str_match` from the `stringr` package, which returns a matrix with the original string in the first column and each extracted part in the other columns.

I found about a dozen regular expressions to extract these two parts. (The parts are a ladder and rung on a pay schedule, and it's very messy. I've verified that my regexes work by defining a function with a bunch of nested `ifelse` statements.)

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
my_strs <- c("A 01","G 00","A    2")
mydt <- data.table(strs = my_strs)

rx1 <- '^([[:alpha:]] )([[:digit:]]{2})$'
rx2 <- '(A)    ([[:digit:]])'
```

I want to check the regexes in sequence and extract the parts using the first one that checks out. If I only had one regex, I could do this:

```
myfun <- function(x){
    y <- str_match(x,rx1)
    return(y)
}
mydt[,myfun(strs)] 
#      [,1]   [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A 01" "A " "01"
# [2,] "G 00" "G " "00"
# [3,] NA     NA   NA
```

(It took me a long time to even get that to work, trying all combinations of `Vectorize` and `as.list` on the function and `*apply`ing in the call.)

My best attempt at checking the regexes in sequence is this rather ugly kludge:

```
myfun2 <- function(x){
    y <- str_match(x,rx1)
    ifelse(!is.na(y[1]),"",(y <- str_match(x,rx2))[1])
    return(y)
}
mydt[1:2,myfun2(strs)] 
#      [,1]   [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A 01" "A " "01"
# [2,] "G 00" "G " "00"
mydt[3,myfun2(strs)] 
#      [,1]     [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A    2" "A"  "2" 
mydt[1:3,myfun2(strs)]
#      [,1]   [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A 01" "A " "01"
# [2,] "G 00" "G " "00"
# [3,] NA     NA   NA
```

As you can see, it doesn't quite work yet.

Do you have any idea about a better way to approach this? I have about 3.5 m rows in my data set, but only about 2000 unique values for this string, so I'm not really worried about efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `strapply` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com).  We define a function that accepts the matches and returns the first two non-empty ones.  Then use it with the regular expression `paste(rx1, rx2, sep = "|")` for each component of `my_str` :

```
library(gsubfn)

# test data
# there was an addition to the question in the comments.  It asked to be able to handle
# one regular expression which has only a single capture.  Make sure its at the end.
rx3 <- "^([[:digit:]]{2})$"
my_strs2 <- c(my_strs, "99")    

# code
first2 <- function(...) { x <- c(..., NA); head(x[x != ""], 2) }
strapply(my_strs2, paste(rx1, rx2, rx3, sep = "|"), first2, simplify = TRUE)
```

The last line returns:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A " "G " "A"  "99"
[2,] "01" "00" "2"  NA
```

(If there are components of `my_strs` that do not match at all then a list will be returned in which those components are NULL.  In that case you may prefer to drop the `simplify = TRUE` and always have it return a list.)

*Note:* `strapplyc` in the same package is **much** faster than `strapply` since the guts of it are written in tcl (a string processing language) whereas `strapply` is written in R.  Thus you might want to break it up this way to leverage off of the faster routine:

```
L <- strapplyc(my_strs2, paste(rx1, rx2, rx3, sep = "|"))
sapply(L, first2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Gabor! I have one regex associated with codes that have no first part. For example, the code might be `"02"` and my regex for these is `"^()([[:digit:]]{2})$"`. I suspect this would run afoul of the approach in your answer. Do you have an idea for how to deal with that case?

Comment: Have updated response to allow for a regular expression with one capture. It must be the last regular expression.  Note that the regular expression was modified to remove the `()` which is not desirable here.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the answer and for introducing your package.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here is another solution I found today:

```
mydt[,{
    i_rx <- min(which(unlist(sapply(rx_list,function(x)grepl(x,strs)))))
    as.list(str_match(strs,rx_list[[i_rx]]))
},by=1:nrow(mydt)]
```

I made some minor alterations to the regexes and put them in a list.

```
rx1  <- '^([[:alpha:]] )([[:digit:]]{2})$'
rx2a <- "^(A)    ([[:digit:]])$"
rx3a <- "^()([[:digit:]]{2})$"
rx_list <- list(rx1,rx2a,rx3a)
```